# Packet Loss with Cisco 2621 Router

Tags: cisco, nat, ping

I'm working with a Cisco 2621 and NAT to map ip addresses to machines in my cluster.  Starting yesterday, I noticed heavy packet loss (60% loss reported by ping) to one ip address mapped to three ports on the same machine.  However, all of the other ip addresses were responding fine and I experienced no packet loss when pinging the same machine from within the cluster.  This continued until today, when I reset the routes (deleted and re-added all three NAT entries).  Now pings appear to report no packet loss.

I haven't modified my router configuration in months.  Does anyone have any idea what may have happened?  I'd like to prevent another occurrence of this in the future.

Thanks,
-Harish

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have 3 NICs configured with one IP address on the same machine? How are they configured, as a bridge? If so, how are you avoiding briding loops? Is Spanning-Tree Protocol being used?

Comment: What's the actual load on your 2621?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm not sure how one can analyze such a behavior when it's not occuring anymore. Maybe there was some kind of ARP messup. Could you post the *sanitized* relevant parts of your config?

Comment: I'd rather not post too many details.  I had three nat entries which looked like:
ip nat inside source static tcp [internal ip] [internal port] [external ip] [external port] extendable

I admittedly am not a router expert so I'm not sure if I'm doing anything obviously wrong here - any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the counters on the router? At the time this was occurring did you look at memory and CPU usage on the router? I've had a few cases of packet loss caused by increased memory usage (about 50% memory use in my case).

Comment: How do I check 'counters'?  What are they?  I didn't look at either memory usage or CPU usage - if it happens again, I'll be sure to do so.

Comment: You can type show interface counters errors or something along these lines.